# How to toggle between vim-emulation and no-vim-emulation when the vscodevim extension is installed?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I haven't found a way to quickly do this without having to entirely disable the extension in the "Extensions" panel. In IntelliJ IDEA, one can easily toggle on/off the emulation with a configurable keyboard shortcut.  I guess it should also be possible in VSCode.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

VSCode has the same command system as atom. These commands can be started through the "command palette" and also bound to a key-combo.

The corresponding command is `toggleVim`. You can bind this command to a key using the gear-icon > keyboard combos (sry, i don't know how to switch the language for an exact description :) ) > enter "toggleVim" to the searchbar. Then you can assign a combo to it.

Effectively the extension will be disabled or enabled quickly.

Comment: In English, these are "shortcuts": `Manage (the "gear" icon) > Keyboard Shortcuts > Vim: Toggle Vim Mode`

Answer (score 44):

This answer is an extension to [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47914944/5607735).

You can use a keyboard shorcut for `toggleVim` command with the help of [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) in VS code.

For example, here I want to use `Ctrl+Alt+V` to toggle Vim mode on/off. To do this I add the following to `keybindings.json` and save the file.

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+v",
        "command": "toggleVim"
    }
```

You can open `keybindings.json` from command palette `Ctrl+Shift+P`, `>Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.

Please note, you have to be careful to choose only from [unused keybindings](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Unused_keys) in Vim and VS code. `Alt` key combinations are unused in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a new feature within VS Code's user interface (UI), but with VS Code v1.78.2 you can use the UI to assign a user-defined keyboard shortcut to the command `toggleVim`. Here's how:

1. **File** menu > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts [Ctrl+K][Ctrl+S]**
2. Search for `toggleVim`
3. With the mouse, double-click on the line `Vim: Toggle Vim Mode`
4. When prompted, enter the desired keyboard shortcut—e.g., `ctrl+alt+v`— and then press `ENTER` to save this change.

At the bottom of the VS Code window, in the status bar, you'll see either `-- VIM: DISABLED --` or `-- NORMAL --` (i.e., Vim enabled) after pressing the chosen keyboard shortcut for the `toggleVim` command.