# Use in Visual Studio Code (Vim extension) CAPS instead of ESC

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I use Debian and I switched from Vim to Visual Studio Code, when I noticed, that there is a Vim movement extension for VS Code from vscodevim. While I was using Vim, I mapped my <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> key to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. In Vim it works perfectly, but VS Code is not reacting on a <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> input.

I hope there is a solution. If there are any questions feel free to ask.

This is how I changed my keyboard layout:
I navigated to /etc/default/
and edited the keyboard file. This is how it looks now

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

The <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> key works also in other programs e.x. "Synaptic Package Manager"

Comment: How did you map Caps lock? Do other applications see the mapping, or just Vim?

Comment: Thanks; that'll help. I use Ubuntu, and did the same remapping via the GNOME Tweak Tool (Make Caps Lock an additional ESC key). It works in all applications, too. I don't have Visual Studio Code, though.

Answer (score 132):

Late answer, but may be useful for someone:

Switched <kbd>CAPS</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> in Ubuntu over the keyboard preferences section. Worked in almost all applications, but not in Visual Studio Code.

So I modified VS Code settings:

```json
{
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: Is it me or this option has since disappeared ?

Comment: @cassepipe 2022 Aug, still works for me.

Comment: you are a hero; this worked for me

Comment: It works on PopOs(ubuntu-based linux).

Comment: This is the answer I have been searching for thank!

Comment: 2023 - still works

Comment: Oct 2023 - Works! Thanks a lot1

Comment: Does not work for me (Kubuntu 23.04) - vscode gets the keydown, but not the keyup...

Comment: Mostly leaving this comment for myself the next time I have to do this: to get to this config file, press <C-S-p> and look for `>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`

Comment: Same issue and solution here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2859

Comment: I works on Debian 12 / VSC 1.87

Answer (score 21):

For those who have the same problems on Linux:

If in your system wide config, Caps Lock is Esc, Esc is Caps Lock ( ['caps:swapescape'] ),

1. disable the key mapping in your system. Make it default.
2. In VSCode, press ctrl+shift+p and select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Sortcuts`
3. search for the `vim_escape`
4. double click on it and press original Caps Lock and save it.
5. Edit your keymap config in your system.

That is it.
There is no problem. Keys are working as expected.

Comment: This would not be the best solution if you like swapping Caps ans Esc system wide.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as expected. The caps lock has the unintended consequence of changing the letterCase (go figure!). So if we're in upperCase in normal mode, then all the keybindings are interpreted as their uppercase versions. If we look at the insert, then it's too tedious, cause all the letters are typed as uppercase, unless you manually hold shift for each key. All round bad answer. Would retract my upvote if I could

Comment: On another note, this could work, if mentally we understand that vim_escape requires two strokes of the Caps Lock key, in order to circumvent the upperCase letter bindings.

Answer (score 8):

1. Set the Caps-lock to act as Esc in your settings
2. Post this in your keybindings json for vscode (Ctrl-K Ctrl-S -> open the JSON from the icon on the top right corner):

```
  {
    "key": "capslock",
    "command": "extension.vim_escape",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
  },
```

If you are looking for a system wide tool, you might be interested in keyd https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd. You can avoid this setup. The readme has an example on how setup caps lock as both ctrl and esc.

Comment: I tried this, and it fixes it for editing code, but not for swapping capslock and escape all over vscode. For instance, you must still use the escape key to cancel a dialog or close the search bar.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu solution

- First make sure you swaped escape with capslock like: <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008072/1425586)</sup>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:swapescape']"
```

- Then inside VSCode press `ctrl+shift+p` search for `Preferences: Open keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` *(it will open `keybindings.json`)* and  paste:

```json
    {
        "key": "capslock",
        "command": "extension.vim_escape",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
    },
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "-extension.vim_escape",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl"
    }
```

- Reload VSCode and you are good to go.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this, and it fixes it for editing code, but not for swapping capslock and escape all over vscode. For instance, you must still use the escape key to cancel a dialog or close the search bar.

Answer (score 4):

Enlighten by an answer from this question.
[In Visual Studio Code, how to toggle between vim-emulation and no-vim-emulation when the vscodevim extension is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502318/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-toggle-between-vim-emulation-and-no-vim-emulation)

Another solution is
Click the `"Gear icon"` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`->type "esc" or "Escape" ->
find `extension.vim_escape` -> edit by click the `pencil icon` or right click choose `change keybinding`
->type you desired key and `ENTER`

Answer (score 1):

## Windows solution

- Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- Go to `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`
- Create a file `caps_to_esc.ahk` and insert code:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe
Capslock::Esc
Esc::Capslock
#IfWinActive
```

- Save, run the file and you are good to go.

Comment: This question is specifically about Debian.

Comment: @amphetamachine I've already posted an [Ubuntu solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73169320/11465149) but, I had a solution for windows too, so I've thought: knowing that there's this tendency in questions that don't explicitly mention on titles or tags anything OS oriented, to see mixed solutions, I decided to post it here. If I've missed any stackoverflow rule, let me know and II'll remove it.

Comment: I was just pointing out that OP, and probably others looking for Linux-specific help, probably won't be able to use your solution. I myself would have included *this* answer under your Ubuntu solution. Oh, and AFAIK, it's not against any rule to post a less-than-optimal answer. If it were, I'd have been banned long ago. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the VIM keys to work normally, the following worked for me with these versions, but the changes do not affect the keyboard shortcuts outside of VSCode:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- VSCode v1.85.1

## Change the dispatch setting

```
(Open VSCode) > File > Preferences > Settings > (Search "keyboard") > User > Application > Keyboard > Keyboard.dispatch > (Select "keyCode")
```

[image]

## Choose your shortcuts

```
(Open VSCode) > File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > (Change whatever)
```

[image]