# Does Vim overwrite all my VS code keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I installed the Vim extension from vs code marketplace just today to use it. I wanted to use Vim's shorctuts for modifying the code. I was unaware that using Vim would disable me to use VS code's shortcuts like `Ctrl + K , Ctrl + O` which opens a folder. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can re-define those keyboard shortcuts. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43206060/2295034

Comment: I doubt the extension has anything to do with Vim itself; it's just providing VSC shortcuts that mirror Vim commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you avoid key binding collisions between VS Code and vscodevim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405783/how-do-you-avoid-key-binding-collisions-between-vs-code-and-vscodevim)