# Issue with Cursor Movement in Code Selection and Line Start in Terminal-like Environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, cursor

When I want to select code or start a new line there appears a block like selecting blinking thing like you have in a terminal, when I want to type it either goes up a line and selecting that line or it is not responding or goes down a line and after I have deleted that line it either restores the whole block of code I deleted or keeps on creating new lines. It is getting on my nerves that I don't know how it is called. what should happen is there needs to be just a small line and not a terminal like block for selecting like you see in the pictures:

[the small line select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYJQg.png)

[the block select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2kiE.png)

this is in VSCode and it just started when I wanted to give .NET and C# a try and after installing those development kits and extensions. I do not know if that has anything to do with this.

I tried google searching but not knowing what to search for is hard, I also tried to look for in the VSCode settings even resetting them did not help. in the VSCode **"setting > Text Editor > Cursor > Cursor style = Line"** and I tried to make it block and then switching back to line, did not work.

Comment: vim extension? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47502318/11107541